# Draw random numbers from a custom probability density function in Julia

Tags: random, julia

I would like to draw random numbers from a modified exponential distribution:

p(x) = C * a * Exp[-(a*x)^b] with C=1/Gamma[1 + 1/b] for normalization.

How can I do this in julia? Unfortunately I have only little experience with Julia and no experiences with creating custom random numbers. I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: The general way to do this is with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, that is a [*p-Generalized Gaussian distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution), which has a rather efficient implementation in [Distributions.jl](https://juliastats.org/Distributions.jl/stable/univariate/#Distributions.PGeneralizedGaussian):

```
using Distributions
mu = 0       # your location parameter
alpha = 1/a  # your scale parameter
beta = b     # your shape parameter
p = PGeneralizedGaussian(mu, alpha, beta)
```

Using the [Distributions.jl API for univariate distributions](https://juliastats.org/Distributions.jl/stable/univariate/#Base.rand-Tuple%7BAbstractRNG,%20UnivariateDistribution%7D), you can sample from this distribution by passing it to the exported `rand` method. Here is an example of how to sample five independent scalars from a `PGeneralizedGaussian` distribution with `mu = 0`, `alpha = 1/2` and `beta = 3`:

```
julia> p = PGeneralizedGaussian(0, 1/2, 3);

julia> rand(p, 5)
5-element Vector{Float64}:
  0.2835117212764108
 -0.023160728370422268
  0.3075395764050027
 -0.19233721955795835
  0.21256694763885342
```

If you want to try to implement the distribution yourself, which I do not recommend unless you are doing this as an exercise in programming math in Julia, you need to define a type that holds the static parameters of the distribution (in your case, just the shape parameter and the scale parameter), then define and export the methods listed [here](https://juliastats.org/Distributions.jl/stable/extends/) to extend the Distributions.jl API to your custom distribution. In particular, you need to define:

```
struct MyDistribution <: ContinuousUnivariateDistribution
  # ... your distribution parameters here
end

rand(::AbstractRNG, d::MyDistribution) # sample a value from d
sampler(d::MyDistribution)             # return d or something that can sample from d more efficiently
logpdf(d::MyDistribution, x::Real)     # compute the log of the pdf of d at x
cdf(d::MyDistribution, x::Real)        # compute the cdf of d at x
quantile(d::MyDistribution, q::Real)   # compute the qth quantile of d
minimum(d::MyDistribution)             # return the minimum value supported by d
maximum(d::MyDistribution)             # return the maximum value supported by d
insupport(d::MyDistribution, x::Real)  # query whether x is supported by d
```

The documentation of the package is very good, so it's an excellent way to get your feet wet if you are trying to learn Julia.

Comment: Thank you! This looks pretty good. There is actually a slight difference in the normalization, because my PDF is only defined for x>=0. But so I think, this can be resolved by just resampling those random numbers, that are negative.

Comment: Ah, forgot that factor of 2 in the normalization factor! If you are using `Distributions.jl`, you might want to also consider using [`t = truncated(p; lower=0)`](https://juliastats.org/Distributions.jl/stable/truncate/#Distributions.truncated) for a more generic way of handling truncated distributions.